# How to hide a specific website folder

Tags: php, apache

I have a question regarding the web application security. I would like to ask you how can I hide a specific folder of my website (in this case the admin) from the public. The admin should be accessible only from two or three IPs.
The admin will be visible as following:
www.mysite.com /admin

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can create an `.htaccess` file and write

```
order deny,allow
deny from all
allow from YOUR_IP #Replace YOUR_IP with the IP you want to allow
allow from YOUR_IP
```

That's about accessing, if you want to hide the file structure, than use

```
IndexIgnore *
```

Answer (score 0):

Combine [a Directory directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#directory) with standard [access control](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/access.html).

```
<Directory /var/www/admin>

    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from 10.10.10.10
    Allow from 10.10.10.11

</Directory>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your post.
I used your script, but I got this error: Internal Server Error

Comment: Internal Server Error means "If you are a user: Something has gone wrong. If you are a developer: Read the server logs for the real error message". Also note that this is supposed to go in an Apache configuration file and not anywhere else.